# Meaning of ガチのM

Tags: meaning, words, katakana

Context: some schoolgirls are talking about a girl that is dating a boy that killed someone when he was younger.

> ついてく男のせいでバカ見てるよね。自分から人生詰みに行ってるよね。**ガチのM**?　夜はあの人殺しから攻められるプレイしてるとか

The only meaning of ガチ I could find was "serious, diligent", but I don't think it fits the context. Judging from what the girl says (攻められるプレイ) and from results in Google for ガチのM, I guess the M stands for masochism. Is this correct? If yes, could you explain the meaning of ガチ and how it can be used to form words? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this M stands for *masochist*. This initialism is very common in Japanese, and people don't usually bother to say マゾ or マゾヒスト in conversations. In this context M primarily means the girl is a type of person who willingly take troubles and put herself in a hard situation. Of course the last sentence has a sexual meaning.

ガチ is *genuine*, *true*, or *real* rather than *diligent*. ガチ is from a sumo-term ガチンコ, which is an antonym for 八百長. So "not a fake/mock" is the original meaning of ガチ.