# Meaning of Sな気質

Tags: japanese-to-english

From this screenshot, which I think is from ひぐらしのなく頃に命, Shion says she might have 'Sな気質', or an S-temperament. What does that mean? I tried googling, but the results are beyond my level of Japanese.

> 私って、Sな気質なのかもしれませんねー。
> もっとも、こんな感じに気安く接するのは
> サトシくんに対してなんです

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fd-SD7eUUAENhbg?format=jpg&name=large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This S is the opposite of [M](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59285/5010).

> 私って、Sな気質なのかもしれませんねー。
> I may have a bit of sadistic temperament!

Although this is originally a term related to sexual pleasure, whether it has a sexual implication depends on the context.